# Getting records back from many to many fluent nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, join

I made a many to many relationship by following the fluent nhibernate [Getting started tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120315022223/http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started) .

[image]
<sub>(source: [fluentnhibernate.org](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/images/2/24/FirstProjectSchema.png))</sub>

Now I am not sure how to retrieve data. For instance what happens if I want to get all the products a store carries.

So I would need to use the storeId on the products table. Yet there is no storeId in the products table and I don't have a class that actually contains mapping or properties for StoreProduct.

So I can't go

```
session.Query<StoreProduct>().Where(x => x.StoreId == "1").toList();
```

So do I need to do a join on Store and Products and then do a query on them?

**Edit**

Here is a watered down version of what I have.

```
      public class Student
        {
            public virtual Guid StudentId { get; private set; }
            public virtual IList<Course> Courses { get; set; }
            public virtual IList<Permission> Permissions{get; set;}
    
    
            public Student()
            {
               Courses = new List<Course>();
               Permissions = new List<Permission>();
            }

     public class StudentMap : ClassMap<Student>
        {
            public StudentMap()
            {
                Table("Students"); 
                Id(x => x.StudentId).Column("StudentId");
                HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions).Table("PermissionLevel");
                HasManyToMany(x => x.Courses).Table("PermissionLevel");
            }
        }

  public class CourseMap : ClassMap<Course>
    {
        public CourseMap()
        {
            Table("Courses");
            Id(x => x.CourseId).Column("CourseId");
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions ).Table("PermissionLevel");
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Students).Table("PermissionLevel");
        }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public virtual int CourseId { get; private set; }
        public virtual IList<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Student> Students { get; set; }


        public Course()
        {
            Permissions = new List<Permission>();
            Students = new List<Student>();
        }
    }

  public class PermissionMap : ClassMap<Permission>
    {
        public PermissionMap()
        {
            Table("Permissions");
            Id(x => x.PermissionId).Column("PermissionId");
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Students).Table("PermissionLevel");
        }
    }

 public class Permission
    {
        public virtual int PermissionId { get; private set; }
        public virtual IList<Student> Students {get; set;}

        public Permission()
        {
            Students = new List<Student>();
        }
    }


 var a = session.Query<Student>().Where(x => x.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
            var b = session.Get<Student>(a.StudentId).Courses;
```

error what I get when I look into b.

> could not initialize a collection:
> [Student.Courses#757f27a2-e997-44f8-b2c2-6c0fd6ee2c2f][SQL:
> SELECT courses0_.Student_id as
> Student3_1_, courses0_.Course_id as
> Course1_1_, course1_.CourseId as
> CourseId2_0_, course1_.Prefix as
> Prefix2_0_, course1_.BackgroundColor
> as Backgrou3_2_0_ FROM PermissionLevel
> courses0_ left outer join Courses
> course1_ on
> courses0_.Course_id=course1_.CourseId
> WHERE courses0_.Student_id=?]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong mappings for Student:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions).Table("PermissionLevel");
HasManyToMany(x => x.Courses).Table("PermissionLevel");
```

It should be following:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Courses).Table("StudentCourses");
```

And you Student class is incomplete.

Comment: incomplete in what way. I can't use PermissionLevel table for both?

Comment: @chobo2 there is no collection Permissions that is present in mappings. According to this code, line `HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions).Table("PermissionLevel");` should not compile

Comment: ah I removed that by mistake when copying the example over.

Comment: @chobo2 will you update them? I cannot check your mappings without that property.

Comment: Ok I added the property back to the student class.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't. StoreProduct is special table that hold many-to-many relations between Store and Products. NHibernate able to populate Store's collection of products using this table automatically. It should be described in mapping. You should query just like this:

```
var storeProducts = session.Get<Store>(1).Products;
```

Here's mapping for Store:

```
public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
{
  public StoreMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    HasMany(x => x.Staff)
      .Inverse()
      .Cascade.All();
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
     .Cascade.All()
     .Table("StoreProduct");
  }
}
```

Notice line `HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)` and `.Table("StoreProduct")` they tell NHibernate to use table **StoreProduct** as source for many-to-many relation store objects in collection **Products**.

Comment: @gor - So I should have mapping in my file about it then. Maybe I missed that. Also you line does not compile .Get<Store>() seems to want an object id.

Comment: @gor - I keep getting "could not initialize a collection:"

Comment: @chobo2 Could you post full stacktrace ? And mappings with entities would be useful too

Comment: @gor - it does not actually give a stacktrack. It's an NHibernate.ADOException but does not cause the program to crash. I will post something up in a few minutes.